# Why run multiple containers of the same docker image in single EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am new to docker and my question is based on the following Reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/p7d12j/why_run_multiple_docker_instances_of_1_image_in/

Some comments in the thread alluded to load balacing as a reason for why someone might want to spin up multiple containers of the same image, but I do not understand how that would apply for spinning up multiple containers in the same EC2 instance.

My scenario: I have a simple backend server that is serving requests over HTTP.

My question: I understand that there are some workloads which can benefit from the ability to spin up and destroy containers on the fly. And please correct me if I am wrong, but I don't see a strong reason for doing that in this case since I just have a simple HTTP server. Hence, I would like to know if there is any other reasons for spinning up multiple containers in the context of a HTTP server? Specifically, I am wondering if is there any difference in resource utilization of 1 container vs 10 containers of the same image running on the same EC2 instance? In other words, can 1 container make full use of the RAM and CPU available in the EC2 instance?

Comment: `but I do not understand how that would apply for spinning up multiple containers in the same EC2 instance.` many services are predicated on short lived containers. The same image. The ability to create and destroy these at minimal cost is a huge appeal and a big advantage of containers.

Comment: More containers use more resources, each has an overhead, but it's likely not a large overhead. One recent use of multiple containers was processing items off a queue - a new container is created for each message so they're processed in parallel rather than sequentially. This was Fargate, but it would work in EC2 as well, Fargate can be roughly 10x more expensive than EC2 for container hosting particularly when the number of CPUs is high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the software in the container has an internal bottleneck or inefficiency, or can explicitly make use of limited resource (such as CPU cores) then running multiple containers can increase scalability to make better use of hardware.

I'd guess that you'd have to be serving a fairly high volume of data to notice much difference.

Your question is really too vague to answer. The best answer is probably "benchmark your software".